# Migrate from Local to Domain login - Win7Pro

Tags: user-profiles, windows-domain

I have a desktop computer that I just upgraded from Win7 HomePrem to Win7 Pro.

I have added a Win2008 server to the environment, and I would like to start logging in to my desktop with a domain credential.

Is there a clean way to do this without losing my profile & settings?

Comment: Converting a local profile to a domain profile without losing anything is close to impossible. Do yourself a favor and just switch to the domain profile, copy over all files you can (like pictures, documents, ...) and then just start using the new profile until you forget about the local one :P

Comment: I have heard that, but I figured I would toss it out here - perhaps there's a utility....

heh: maybe the people down-voting this question know that the answer is SO OBVIOUS they won't even deign to type it in.

Comment: Yes, there is a tool. It's called the [User State Migration Tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560801(v=ws.10).aspx). But it's not what you would hope for it to be. There are basically sets of conversion instructions for every single application that could be installed on a workstation and it only comes with a very small set of instructions, like for Office. The idea is that you would use this if you have hundreds of accounts to convert, otherwise it's not worth it. Btw, it seems like this question is a duplicate, I'll close it. Maybe the other one helps you.

Comment: Interesting - that question did not come up in the list of possibly-similar questions I reviewed before posting.